# In the group $U(12)$, what would be the elements of the subgroup $H = \langle7\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am not sure how to begin this problem. An explanation with the answer would be great!

As a follow up what would the left cosets of $H$ be?

Comment: $7\cdot 7=49=1$ mod $12$

Comment: As janmarqz wrote, there are only two elements in $\langle{7}\rangle$...

Comment: Thanks. How would I compute the left cosets of this subgroup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we know  $U(n)$ is the set of integers that are relatively prime to $n$ so, $$U(12)=\{1,5,7,11\}$$ and we know it is a group under multiplication modulo $12$, for example: $$5\cdot_{12}7=35=24+11=11\to 5\cdot 7=11$$ and so on. Here, as you're commented $H=\langle 7\rangle=\{1,7\}$ and indeed, for any $g\in U(12)$, $$gH=\{gh|h\in H\}$$ Now set $g=1$ and so $1H=H$. Set $g=5$ so $5H=\{5,11\}$.Set $g=7\in H$ so $7H=H$. Set $g=11$ so $11H=\{11,77\}=\{11,5\}$.